# pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle gows funny for big circles, any alternatives?

Tags: python, pygame, draw, antialiasing, geometry

Working on my Major project for software design and development and have run into the hurdle that when using pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle to draw big circles, the output goes screwy as seen here

[image]

the window in the picture is showing a section of a circle with a radius of size 1561

if no-one can suggest a fix or alternate way of drawing aa circles i will probably just use the regular circle function as it doesn't look to bad at sch a large radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest not to use pygame.gfxdraw, since it is clearly marked as experimental.

From the documentation:

> EXPERIMENTAL!: meaning this api may change, or dissapear in later
>   pygame releases. If you use this, your
>   code will break with the next pygame
>   release.

Just stick with the regular circle function.

**EDIT:**

Maybe you should open a bugreport on [the pygame bugtracker](http://pygame.motherhamster.org/) or the pygame mailinglist.

Comment: Thanks since i cant find any good alternatives and i will stick to regular circles, or aacircles for small objects

Comment: yes, it's a pitty that aacricles are buggy. Maybe I'll have a look at the pygame source code later...

Comment: Their not too bad, they look good for small circles its just big ones that are buggy